# Lessen the acidity of fruit shrub syrup

Tags: flavor

I made a strawberry/cherry shrub for the first time with a 1:1 ratio of fruit juice to white wine vinegar, about 5 cups total, and it turned out just a little too strong for my taste. Is there anything I can add to lessen the vinegar flavor about 10-20%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply change the ratio by adding more fruit juice; otherwise you're into experimental territory by adding alkali almost at random.

Baking soda would reduce the pH, but I'm not hopeful for what it would do to the taste, or look.

Whatever you decide, I'd test it in small portions first.
You may end up just liking it mixed with tonic water... or gin... or...

Comment: Yeah, I figured this might be the only option, but I was hoping someone else would have an idea that didn't require a second batch. But, fair enough, I'll go with this. Thanks!